# using variables in DBUnit load file

Tags: dbunit

Is there a way that i can use variables in my load file in DBUnit so that I can populate dynamic data at runtime

e.g.

```
<Employee id="var" , name="emp1" />
```

and I want the var to be something that I can supply.

Sorry if it is a basic questions but I have just started looking at DBUnit on someone's recommendation

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution a couple of days before, you could use ReplacementDataSet. Here is an example(I use it to replace some fields with null)

```
public static IDataSet flatXml(File file)
        throws MalformedURLException, DataSetException {
    ReplacementDataSet dataSet = new ReplacementDataSet(
            new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(file));
    dataSet.addReplacementObject("[NULL]", null);
    return dataSet;
}

<dataset>
    <T_F2G_PENDING_ORDER 
        TRACKING_ID="2"
        DELIVERY_TIME="2013-04-01 13:44:00"
        DELIVERY_ADDRESS_STREET1="North Che Zhan Road"
        DELIVERY_ADDRESS_STREET2="Kui Zhao Road" 
        RESTAURANT_ID="[NULL]" />
</dataset>
```

Hope this helps.